# PowerShell to export multiple variables to csv?

Tags: powershell, csv

General Information

```
$ComputerSystem = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select -Property Model , Manufacturer , Description , PrimaryOwnerName , SystemType
```

Boot Configuration

```
$BootConfiguration = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BootConfiguration | Select -Property Name , ConfigurationPath
```

BIOS Information

```
$BIOS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BIOS | Select -Property PSComputerName , Manufacturer , Version #| Export-Csv -InputObject
```

Operating System Information

```
$OS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select -Property Caption , CSDVersion , OSArchitecture , OSLanguage
```

I want to export all these variables to a csv file with headings but I am unable to.

Comment: Create a custom object that contains all properties you want in your csv file and pipe it to export-csv like kohlbrr suggests

Comment: Think about the structure of the CSV file you want - it will make things clearer (write down an example file manually with the column headings and sample content).

Comment: Two of your variables have a Manufacturer property.

Answer (score 1):

The following combines the noteproperties from each object created separately by the get-wmiobject commands to the $report variable. From there you can export to csv.

This could be better simplified with loops that go through each variable created by the gwmi calls and add the noteproperties to the report variable.

```
$ComputerSystem = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select -Property Model , Description , PrimaryOwnerName , SystemType
$BootConfiguration = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BootConfiguration | Select -Property Name , ConfigurationPath 
$BIOS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BIOS | Select -Property PSComputerName , Manufacturer , Version 
$OperatingSystem = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select -Property Caption , CSDVersion , OSArchitecture , OSLanguage  

$report = New-Object psobject
$report | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Model -Value $ComputerSystem.Model
$report | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Description -Value $ComputerSystem.Description
$report | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name PrimaryOwnerName -Value $ComputerSystem.PrimaryOwnerName
$report | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name SystemType -Value $ComputerSystem.SystemType
$report | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Name -Value $BootConfiguration.Name
$report | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name ConfigurationPath -Value $BootConfiguration.ConfigurationPath
$report | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name PSComputerName -Value $BIOS.PSComputerName
$report | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Manufacturer -Value $BIOS.Manufacturer
$report | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Version -Value $BIOS.Version
$report | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Caption -Value $OS.Caption
$report | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name CSDVersion -Value $OS.CSDVersion
$report | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name OSArchitecture -Value $OS.OSArchitecture
$report | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name OSLanguage -Value $OS.OSLanguage

$report | export-csv .\file.csv -NoTypeInformation
```